# How can I plot just the colorbar of a heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot just the colorbar for a heatmap. Here is a MWE:

```
import seaborn as sns
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


A = np.random.rand(100,100)

g = sns.heatmap(A)
plt.show()
```

How can I plot just its colorbar and not the heatmap itself?

Comment: `g.clear()` at the end ? If you don't want to show axes, add `plt.axis('off')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to handle it manually:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 4))
# vmin, vmax =  np.nanmin(A), np.nanmax(A)
cmap = mpl.colormaps['rocket']
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(0, 1)  # or vmin, vmax
cbar = fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, cmap), ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plotting just the colorbar is not possible to my knowledge. To see the whole spectrum of the colorbar, you could use a sample heatmap that is just a range from 0 to 100:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [[a] for a in range(100)] # sample heatmap

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.heatmap(A, cbar=False, ax=ax)

cax = fig.add_axes([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])  # Adjust the position and size

plt.show()
```

[image: Output of the snippet]

Comment: ...and it looks beautiful aswell ;)

Comment: I would really like to just plot the colorbar as I want to put into my presentation separately.

Comment: Use snipping tool to cut just colors..

Comment: @GedasMiksenas It would be great if it could all be done in Python

Comment: Use this with the above code 'ax.set_axis_off()' and 'cax.set_axis_off()'. This is closest what I can think of.